# Codigniter Cross-Origin Ajax Calls Not Picking Up Session Information

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have CI 3 setup on a localhost for development with an example domain in my host file and wildcard ServerAlias in httpconf. The urls load perfectly, and the login code runs fine, saves the session and I can navigate the system logged in.

As soon as I send an ajax request to a subdomain of my test domain, the session in CI seems to be lost, so it can't authenticate the user is logged in.

Say the domain(s) in my hosts file are:

```
127.0.0.1 testdomain.com
127.0.0.1 test1.testdomain.com
127.0.0.1 test2.testdomain.com
```

CodeIgniter config as the cookie_domain = ".testdomain.com".

I can login to the system at http://testdomain.com:81 but as soon as I send a request via $.post (jQuery) to http://test1.testdomain.com or test2. it responds with my verify login code saying the session is empty.

I have

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

at the top of the controller that the ajax is calling.

Any ideas?

Comment: research `ajax withCredentials` which allows sending cookies cross domain

Answer (score -1):

You should use $.jsonp() instead of using $.post() if come to the Cross-Origin request problem.